# JUnit - Accessing TestResult from TestSuite

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, test-suite

My TestSuite is running during the build using ant target.
I would like, in my suite, to access the TestResult and do some actions if the tests succeed or not.
Is there a way to retrieve the object in the tear down method?
Thanks

Comment: not sure why would you need to access it from the test code itself. However if you just need to change results somehow, this could help: http://www.skill-guru.com/blog/2010/03/26/generating-junit-test-results-as-html-report/ . To be honest manipulating results in the test itself sounds suspicious :)

Comment: Not at all I'm going to manipulate the results. I just want to read them in order to notify some other build actions to do stuff.

Comment: well in that case, you can use the way suggested, as in such a case you can decouple tests from the the triggers (what I would consider beeing an advantage compared to the other approach)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With jUnit3 I'd try subclassing `Test` and overwrite the `run` method. That would provide me with access to the `TestResult` instance. Something like this:

```
public class MyTest extends Test {
  @Overwrite
  public void run(TestResult result) {
    super.run(result);
    doSomethingWithResults(result);
  }

  // ...
}
```

With jUnit4 I'd look into implementing a TestRunner (based on the standard runner). It sounds difficult but actually isn't. Subclass the default one and simply add the `@RunWith` annotation to use your own runner (that can do something with the results)

Comment: Thanks. Should I change `@RunWith` in my suite or in the test classes?

Comment: And another question, do you have any experience collecting such information? Do you know where can I find it? It it not difficult implementing the runner, indeed, but I couldn't find info about the test results...

Comment: Extend the default runner, which is [`BlockJUnit4ClassRunner`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.html), then overwrite [`run`](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/ParentRunner.html#run(org.junit.runner.notification.RunNotifier). I think, you have to write a custum `RunNotifier` too that wraps the one that you get and allows to intercept the fail notifications. To your question: no, never did it, but it looks like the way to go.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up extending `RunListener`, and added it to the `RunNotifier` I'm getting in `run`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Cool :) Whenever I need something like this, I'll come back to my answer :)